Is there another topology on a given set which makes closures equal?
In a research article about Lindelöfness, I saw a topological space.  Let $A=\{a,b\}$, $B=\{c_{i}: i<\omega_{1}\}$ and $C=\{a_{ij}: i<\omega_{1}, j\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{b_{ij}: i<\omega_{1}, j\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Consider $X=A\cup B\cup C$ with the topology such that the points $\{a_{ij}\}$ and $\{b_{ij}\}$ are isolated and $U_{c_{i}}^{n}=\{c_{i}\}\cup\{a_{ij}:j\geq n\}\cup\{b_{ij}: j\geq n\}$, $U_{a}^{\alpha}=\{a\}\cup\{a_{ij}: i\geq\alpha, j\in\mathbb{N}\}$, $U_{b}^{\alpha}=\{b\}\cup\{b_{ij}:i\geq\alpha, j\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are the fundamental system of neighborhoods of the points $\{c_{i}\}$, $a$ and $b$, respectively. (Example 3.5. in https://eudml.org/doc/47631). Is there any topology $\sigma$ on $X$ such that the closure of each open set $U$ with respect to $\tau$ is equal to closure of $U$ with respect to $\sigma$? Since I am pretty much confused to set up a such topology, any help would greatly be aprreciated.

I am sorry for the confusing type. I edited the question @Ulli

If you can tell me what is confusing, I may try to explain it. @Ulli

in my notation above, $A$ have only 2 elements $a$ and $b$. B is an uncountable set indexed with the set $S=[0,\omega_{1})$ where $\omega_{1}$ is the smallest uncountable ordinal. and $C$ is the set consisting of all $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ where $i\in S$ and $j\in\mathbb{N}$ all $a_{ij}$ different from each other and all $b_{ij}$ different from each other such $a_{11},b_{12}$ etc. Hence $C$ is another uncountable set and $X$ is the union of $A, B$ and $C$. @Ulli

Again, what is $a$, what is $b$? What is $a_{ij}$ etc?
Might be $A = {0,1}$,
$C = {(\alpha,j): \alpha < \omega_1, j \in \mathbb N} \cup {(\alpha,-j): \alpha < \omega_1, j \in \mathbb N}$
(with $0 \notin \mathbb N$, hence $(\alpha,j) \neq (\alpha,-j)$)?

exactly we can consider it as well you noted. @Ulli

we may consider $A={\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}}$ @Ulli

You seem to give a definition of a topology on $X$, but don't name it $\sigma$ or $\tau$ (maybe it's $\sigma$?). And then you ask if we can have $\sigma$ and $\tau$ with the same closures or open sets. Why can't I just take $\sigma=\tau$? It seems like I or the question is missing some key info.

I gave the definition of the topology $\tau$. And I wanted to ask another topology $\sigma$ different from $\tau$  on $X$ such that closure of every open $U$ with respect to $\tau$ is equal to the closure of $U$ with respect to $\sigma$ @MarkS.
